# Show cursor previews in Windows Explorer after associating with a program

Tags: windows-7, file-association, cursor

When I associate cursor files with an editor Windows 7 shows the program's icon instead of the preview of the cursor itself so how do I associate the cursor with the editor without losing the Windows Explorer preview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the ContextEdit program released by PC Magazine to create an edit association between cursors and the cursor editing program Greenfish Icon Editor Pro instead of using Windows Explorer's default method.